# Charging NiMHs: about current fluctuation tolerance

Tags: nimh

While trying to make a DIY charging system on my bicycle -based on the hub dynamo- I have seen in action that Li-Ion batteries (typical 18650 ones) do not like charging current fluctuation at all. They hate it and you will soon end with a useless power bank in the middle of nowhere - alas.

I then thought of a hand crank system, to turn the wheel constantly with the bicycle upside down. It works, but time is the problem: I have to spend half an hour of my every bicycle touring day for this. Instead if I could have the charging module connected on the hub all the day long - with the bike stopping and starting all the time - that would be cool and perfect. It is simply a matter of practicality.

I am wondering what if I use NiMHs in the power bank batteries module instead of Li-ions.

So the question comes: do NiMH batteries withstand current fluctuation acceptably well for this case?

Comment: Clear XY problem!

Comment: @winny - i guess you mean that the real cause of the problem is not what i think it is. Any clue appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Batteries are perfectly happy with intermittent charging current, whether Li or Ni based.

However, a charger that tries to be too clever, too smart, like your useless power bank one, may get confused by stop-start charging and do the wrong thing, or shut down, or fail safe.

Do not replace Li batteries with Ni ones in the same power bank module, that will totally confuse the charger, different voltage, different chemistry.

If you stay within the voltage and current limits for your battery, they will charge OK.

Note that Ni based batteries will tolerate a steady overcharge. Li based batteries will not. That would make a considerable difference to the charger.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Neil, now I can scratch my head more. :-) My experience insists that the batteries may be happy with what I am not at all, but i may be wrong. ;-)